# How can I load image on Picasso?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, picasso

How can I load image on android studio by using Picasso libary. I tried it before but no image shown...
Note: Libary implementation, Internet access permission everything I do correctly but nothing happened...

Comment: Please share the code of what you have tried.

Comment: Show more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the example to load the image with Picasso.

```
 Picasso.with(mcontext).load(URLDecoder.decode(current.getImage(), "UTF-8"))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.program)
                .into(holder.imageView);
```

Share your code here so we can check.